# How to get value of hiddenfield in another form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

iIhave value in hdnField in form1.aspx . I assign a value to hdnfield in javascript .I want to get that value in aspx.vb in another form, form2.aspx. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Don't you think that you should be more specific? "I want to get that value in serverside in another form" is not something where I can understand what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If your Form1.aspx submits to Form2.aspx, then you have atleast a few ways to access the value of form fields (including Hidden fields):

- The Request.Form property exposes a `NameValueCollection` containing all submitted form field names as Keys and their values as Values. You could use the syntax `Request.Form["fieldName"]` to access the value.
- If this is ASP.NET 2+ and you used the Cross-page posting technique, you will be able to access field values in the previous page using the `PreviousPage` property of the Page.
- If you use `Server.Transfer`, you can access values using the Current `HttpContext`.

If you need more info, you should take a look at [Passing values between pages in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think your concept of session is wrong. Session is a server-side object, and javascript runs on the client, so you can not directly assign that value to a session. You can, instead, use some AJAX to send it to the server and then add code in the server so the value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... you have to think about the difference between serverside and clientside first... 
You cant directly access changes you made in the client on the serverside, because you once send a request to server, as a response you get the site diplayed in your browser. As soon as you recieve the request, the server is finished and cant access the site anymore. Its like a letter you send away. As soon as you put it into the mailbox, you cant make changes anymore.
But you could post a new request to the server and add POST or GET peremeters. These can be accessed by the server. The way you send the request doesnt matter... you can send a request using AJAX or simply reload the page.